# Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr when start Instruments

Tags: iphone, instruments

I am developing a iPhone app and everything works fine so far. I can build and start the app in the simulator. But when I now start the app with Instruments I got the error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

I've googled but did not find a solution.

Hope somebody can help me out. Thx

Comment: I'm assuming you have Security.Framework added. What other frameworks do you have in the project.

Comment: Same problem here. I don't have Security.Framework added.

Comment: I also have this problem and I am *not* linking to the Security AFAIK.

Comment: When you say, you did not find a solution, does that mean, you have already looked at the [deprecated code](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/09/developing-on-snow-leopard/) problem or the [libcurl](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4580-curl-anyone-using-their-app-2.html) one? (also @Ben)

Comment: How about adding the Security.Framework and see if that works.

Comment: i found this that is similar 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean/8317546#8317546 ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're linking against the Security.Framework and possibly libcurl. Try starting a new default project and see if you can compile it without this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all of the frameworks that you are linking in your Target one at a time (and presumably also removing any code that relies on those frameworks). I found that having either CoreVideo or CoreMedia linked with a Target you were building for the iPad simulator caused a crash with this message.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error and it was a red herring, the actual problem was an Assertion failure. Tracked it down by add an Xcode 4 breakpoint on all exceptions. http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2011/04/18/xcode-4-exception-breakpoint/