# Universal App won't run on iPad Simulator

Tags: iphone, porting, core-foundation, universal-binary, ios-simulator

I have an existing iPhone app that I'm trying to convert into a universal app for both iPhone and iPad. Everything seems to work fine when I run it on an iPad device, but I get the following runtime error when I try to run in the iPad simulator:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

I am building using the latest 4.1 SDK. My project settings are set to build for iPhone/iPad. My deployment target is set to iOS 3.1. I have weakly linked to UIKit.framework.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr when start Instruments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281261/symbol-not-found-cfxmlnodegetinfoptr-when-start-instruments)

Comment: For that question, OP was able to run in the simulator but had issues with using certain debugging tools, while I am having trouble with the simulator by itself. While the symptoms look similar, the causes could be different. Also, he is running simulator 3.0 (iPhone), while I am on simulator 3.2 (iPad).

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, but didn't the original iPad ship with iOS 3.2?

Try setting your deployment target to that and try again.  Any better?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which was solved by information provided at https://gist.github.com/1267913 by github user neilinglis, who said,

"It's an SDK bug with the Simulator. If you disable exception breakpoints or just keep going through them then it'll actually all work OK. Everything works fine on the device."