# Swift usage of selector not worked

Tags: ios, swift, selector, osx-yosemite, xcode6.0.1

I have created `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` object in Swift. There are no compile errors/warnings at below line. Clean and build application works perfect.

```
let rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                                  action: "handleGesture:")
                                  ^^^^^ Error Part ^^^^^
```

But It gives an exception on runtime.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __TFSS37_convertFromBuiltinUTF16StringLiteralfMSSFTBp17numberOfCodeUnitsBw_SS
Referenced from:<AppPath>.app/AppName
Expected in: <AppPath>.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
```

Here `<AppPath>` is application path for the simulator.

OS: Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10

Xcode version: Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317)

**What I have tried;**

I am able to figure out that issue is with `action: "handleGesture:"` part. So proper selector is not used here i guess.

I tried with `Selector` but not get done.

1. `NSSelectorFromString("handleGesture:")`
2. `Selector("handleGesture:")`
3. `Selector.convertFromStringLiteral("handleGesture:")`

**Edit:**

The same line/code work for other application. I am not able to figure out why it stops executing from this line where as the same code works for other application.

Comment: Marking the method public or @obcj should work. This way it's name doesn't get mangled.

Comment: It is resolve now. Actually the issue is related to linking. I have used some open source library and the reference of that library I guess broken or not working. Just remove their reference and connect it again resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's working for me

```
var swipeEdit:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("selector:"))
swipeEdit.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left;
element.addGestureRecognizer(swipeEdit);
```

For further details go through the thread in stack overflow

[dyld: Symbol not found: error how to resolve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344560/dyld-symbol-not-found-error-how-to-resolve-this-issue)

Comment: Check edited question, your code works but issue is on application side.

Comment: The link you provided helps me to figure out the cause.

Comment: Yeah that's fine.Happy coding.