# dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_column_table_name Referenced from: libgdal.1.dylib Expected in: libsqlite3.dylib

Tags: xml, homebrew, shapefile, dylib, dyld

I'm really new to homebrew and was trying to convert .shp files to .geojson files by typing this into the terminal

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 one.geojson one.shp
```

Upon which I got the following error message.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_column_table_name
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libgdal.1.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I thought it was similar to [dyld: Symbol not found: error how to resolve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344560/dyld-symbol-not-found-error-how-to-resolve-this-issue)

but am not sure, and the answers in that thread I couldn't decipher. Can someone help?