# Getting dyld_fatal_error Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Seems like it randomly started giving me this fatal error today, no matter which program I try to run.
I don't recall downloading any updates recently...
I can't successfully run any programs, even programs that I know for a fact work.

Call stack:

   Thread 1

0 dyld_fatal_error 
4 _dyld_start

and a breakpoint in some assembly code with a nop instruction

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x7fff5fc01074 <+0>: int3   
->  0x7fff5fc01075 <+1>: nop
```

The console error I get is

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _heim_data_get_bytes
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions  /A/Heimdal
in /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
```

So far, I have tried to clean and build multiple programs. I also relaunched xcode.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Thank you very much for your time.

More information (6/10/15):
From this answer [dyld: Symbol not found: error how to resolve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344560/dyld-symbol-not-found-error-how-to-resolve-this-issue)
It seems that dyld errors are caused by a missing or a bad library linking, not code.

What I find strange is that whatever has changed is suddenly affecting every project I try to run. I have no idea what could have changed.

When I go to the Link Binary With Libraries there aren't any libraries linked.
This would make sense because right now I'm only doing basic objective-c projects as I'm learning. That scenario wouldn't require anything other than foundation which I include in main.m, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well and found another thread (I’m new and haven’t learned how to quote that one yet...) that said to do Product, Clean in Xcode. It worked for me.

I also deleted the DerivedData folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/) and that seemed to eliminate this error from coming back.

In my case, I had been part of an Enterprise Development program, removed myself from it and then enrolled as an individual developer. All of my prior projects were in the DerivedData folder and it was tripping Xcode up.