# How can I see more useful and descriptive errors from Bazel + clang on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, bazel

**Problem:** While trying to setup and run a C++ project with Clang + Bazel + VSCode on Mac, I noticed that the compiler/linker errors that I am getting from `bazel run :main` are not descriptive enough and do not help me debug or find the actual errors themselves. The project used [hedron_compile_commands for linting](https://github.com/hedronvision/bazel-compile-commands-extractor), but the problem occurs without it. When compared to a regular `clang++ main.cc`, I find the errors are much, much better (or using gcc, g++, clang for that matter).

**At a glance:** here is a side-by-side between `bazel run :main` and `clang++ main.cc` runs, where the `clang++` version actually tells me the missing symbol and where the problem is:

```bash
$ bazel clean --expunge  # Just in case
$ bazel run :main
...
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/main
dyld[21237]: missing symbol called
[1]    21237 abort      bazel run :main
```

vs.

```bash
$ clang++ main.cc
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "hello()", referenced from:
      _main in main-1ad55b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

**Minimal Reproducible Example:** To help debug, I removed all project specifics and started a minimum working example (below) that intentionally causes an error. How can I make the error more informative like `clang++` does?

File: `WORKSPACE` *(empty)*

File: `BUILD`

```bash
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["main.cc"],
)
```

File: `main.cc`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Intentionally not defining function hello() to cause symbol not found error.
void hello();

int main() {
  hello();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Other details, if they are helpful:

```bash
$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

$ clang -v
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ bazel --version
bazel 6.2.0-homebrew
```

Subcommand-level printout for bazel (no extra args):

```bash
$ bazel run --subcommands :main
INFO: Analyzed target //:main (4 packages loaded, 36 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
SUBCOMMAND: # //:main [action 'Compiling main.cc', configuration: 0909373ec580d3e2e8ec40b71c3e423e7c33b13b4c974f9aae5bd5b5697a6d2f, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tshur/a61ba18154c69c2d95531d3e0a4c3e62/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/git/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:...(other_PATH_locations_of_mine) \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/_objs/main/main.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/_objs/main/main.pic.o' -fPIC '-DBAZEL_CURRENT_REPOSITORY=""' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c main.cc -o bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/_objs/main/main.pic.o)
# Configuration: 0909373ec580d3e2e8ec40b71c3e423e7c33b13b4c974f9aae5bd5b5697a6d2f
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host
SUBCOMMAND: # //:main [action 'Linking main', configuration: 0909373ec580d3e2e8ec40b71c3e423e7c33b13b4c974f9aae5bd5b5697a6d2f, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tshur/a61ba18154c69c2d95531d3e0a4c3e62/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/git/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:...(other_PATH_locations_of_mine) \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/main-2.params)
# Configuration: 0909373ec580d3e2e8ec40b71c3e423e7c33b13b4c974f9aae5bd5b5697a6d2f
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host
Target //:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.609s, Critical Path: 0.52s
INFO: 8 processes: 6 internal, 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 8 total actions
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/main
dyld[23482]: missing symbol called
[1]    23482 abort      bazel run --subcommands :main
```

Some things I have tried / looked into:

- A lot of command-line options found across bazel github / stack exchange such as `--action_env CC=clang++` `--subcommands` `-c dbg` `--incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution` `CC=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++` `--spawn_strategy=local` `--sandbox_debug` `--strip=never` `--apple_generate_dsym` `--strategy_regexp=^Linking=local` `--features=oso_prefix_is_pwd` `BAZEL_USE_CPP_ONLY_TOOLCHAIN=1`
- I have briefly tried playing with C++ toolchain setting in Bazel, but I would ideally like to find a way to have Bazel automatically detect the correct C++ toolchain
- Tried searching for this issue many, many times. The most similar issues I have seen are where some [#include'd library is showing `dydl` errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344560/dyld-symbol-not-found-error-how-to-resolve-this-issue), but no posts about how to improve this error logging for a regular project. Other [similar issues](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6327) involved getting symbols in `lldb` debugging, but I want the solution to output errors regardless of debugger.

**Where I am now:** My best understanding to date is that the issue I am having is related to the Linker and Mac/OSX. It seems to me that the Linker is finding the error that the symbol is not found (I know this is because the function `hello()` is not defined/implemented). `clang++` is doing a great job of describing the linker error. However, `bazel` seems to be hiding or truncating the error.

From other posts, I have seen that Mac/OSX may be hiding or not storing all of the symbols for `bazel` to use during error reporting? I feel like I am looking for some verbosity or dbg flag, but the ones that I have found and tried (above) do not seem to work. Are there some kind of linkopts that are needed?

Also, I am not certain which compiler `bazel` is using. My best understanding is that it comes from xcode command line tools. I also tried `brew install llvm`, but I am not sure how to point to that.

Please help! Thanks so much in advance for any help ~~

---

**Edit 1:** As @AlanBirtles pointed out, I can pass `bazel run --linkopt="-Wl,-undefined,error" :main` to create a descriptive build-time error (rather than a non-descriptive run-time error).

However, I cannot add `build --linkopt="-Wl,-undefined,error"` to my workspace `.bazelrc`. Otherwise, my other dependencies (e.g., absl) are built with this flag, and they have failures.

```bash
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "absl::random_internal::kRandenRoundKeys", referenced from:
      absl::random_internal::RandenHwAes::GetKeys() in randen_hwaes.pic.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/YGVWGnhFEXc?pli=1

Comment: Hi, thank you for this link: the suggestion to add `bazel run --linkopts="-Wl,-undefined,error" :main` does what I want! However, I can't add this to my workspace `.bazelrc`, otherwise my external dependencies (absl, gtest, etc.) generate linker errors from using this linkopt. Any advice @AlanBirtles?

Comment: I've never used bazel,i just googled your error message

Comment: You can use https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_binary.linkopts for the `cc_binary()`