# What does this gdb output mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator

I've got a button that plays a sound, and it seems to work perfectly fine on the simulator, but i'm getting this message:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.605 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.657 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.671 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.706 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.715 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.732 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2011-11-01 02:13:02.741 Halloween FX[33484:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

And i've had reports saying, on some devices it's not playing at all.

Comment: Just wanted to add I'm seeing this same issue when playing HLS video streams in a iOS project using ARC.

Comment: Also, this links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906930/avaudiorecorder-is-broken-on-ios-5
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31022

Answer (score 203, accepted):

That is a confirmed bug of the iOS SDK 5 / Simulator - happens as soon as the simulator tries to play sound (from a movie or any other sound source). Do not worry though, it won't be a problem on the actual device.

You mentioned actual reports of users having trouble using your App - those problems are not related / connected to the issue you have posted above.

This issue is filed by Apple under Bug ID# 10555404. I did file a report myself which has finally been identified as a dupe of the mentioned bug id.

The issue currently persists up until and including Xcode Version 4.4.1 (4F1003), iOS SDK 5.1.

**Update**

This issue is finally fixed within Xcode Version 4.5 (4G182), iOS SDK 6.0.

**Note**

The issue persists even in Xcode Version 4.5 when used in conjunction with the iOS 5.1 (or lower) simulator.

Comment: Still seeing this issue with LLDB but the annoying delay is gone.

Comment: Looks like this is caused by an internal exception being thrown within AVFoundation on the Simulator. Disabling the "All Exceptions" breakpoint stops the debugger breaking at it and the sound does play, as suggested by Brandon Williams' answer. (Or force the debugger to continue repeatedly and the sound will eventually play.)

Comment: I am still seeing this problem in Xcode 4.5 and with the iOS 6 Simulator + iOS SDK 6.0, no matter what workarounds or suggestions I try to move past it. Hmm ...

Answer (score 16):

I found a temporary workaround to this problem: simply turn off breakpoints before playing the video. Then it works fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

This Problem May occur if you incorrectly import a Mac OSX framework instead of iOs framework. Removing the Mac OS framework worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Use the AVAudioPlayer as ivar in head file with strong :
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer
For me this works.

Answer (score 4):

The following code can be used to test on simulator.

```
if (beep == nil)
    NSLog(@"audio player not initialized");             
else if(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) 
{
    NSLog(@"beep play"); 
} 
else
{
    [beep play];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem many people are having. I didn't find any solution to this yet.

I strongly suggest to file a radar.
Here's mine http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1466402

Comment: Don't worry on Apple becoming silent. I still get feedback on bugs. But this one is so obvious. They should at least figure out the duplicates :(

Answer (score 1):

What Till says is absolutely right. But when using ARC, this problem might correlate (without a causality) with another problem: If the AVAudioPlayer actually doesn't play any sound, this might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744831/838068