# Can't Play Sound on Xcode iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, simulator, avplayer

I am trying to play a sound thats linked to a button, but I get the following error code. How can I fixed this problem?

> 2012-01-13 07:22:58.887 M3NYFAC3Z[5875:1e03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-01-13 07:22:58.892 M3NYFAC3Z[5875:1e03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-01-13 07:25:28.994 M3NYFAC3Z[5875:1e03] AQMEIO_Base::DoStartIO:
>   timeout 2012-01-13 07:25:29.271 M3NYFAC3Z[5875:1e03]
>   AQMEDevice(0x8831a00)::StartIO: error -66681 2012-01-13 07:25:29.272
>   M3NYFAC3Z[5875:1e03] CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying:
>   AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681). [Switching to process 5875
>   thread 0x207] sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)playobey:(id)sender { 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"renegadeyamaha" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Let's see the code for playing the sound.

Comment: Looks similar to this issue (similar but not identical) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean/8317546#8317546.
Posting some code might indeed enlighten us.

Comment: @M3NYFAC3Z have you tried on a device? Does it behave the same?

Comment: Yes I have; It plays no sound.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep a reference to your AVAudioPlayer in an ivar/property somewhere. It's probably being created and then released immediately before it's had a chance to finish playing your sound.

I wrote a little AVAudioPlayer-based sound player class that might make your life easier:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager