# Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr

Tags: iphone

Adding Exception breakpoint and when i set breakpoint on my own to see what is wrong. I see this same error

`2012-02-05 14:12:09.589 imageview[579:1d03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr`

Anyone have any ideas about this error.

Comment: It might be related to a bug mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8317546/194309 and the temp solution is to turn off exception breakpoints, the exact opposite of what you're trying to do...