# (Edit: iOS Simulator 5.x bug) EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using AudioQueue for sound playback in iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, audioqueue

[Edit: It is a confirmed iOS Simulator bug. Appeared in 5.0 and remains in 5.1. See link below in my own answer].

I guys. This is my first question. I'm really lost...

I'm getting some troubles using AudioQueue to play a sound in iOS. I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I create a AudioQueue using AudioQueueNewOutput. It appears to happen in some audio thread (Xcode shows Thread 4).

The AudioQueue is created like this:

```
AudioQueueNewOutput(&desc, audioQueueCallback, this, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), 
kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, &audioQueue);
```

(desc contains the iOS canonical playback format).

This is what the editor shows:

```
AudioToolbox`PowerMeter::PowerMeter():
0x16ee92:  pushl  %ebp
0x16ee93:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x16ee95:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x16ee98:  movb   $0, (%eax)
0x16ee9b:  movl   $0, 8(%eax)
0x16eea2:  movl   $0, 4(%eax)
0x16eea9:  movl   $1064866676, 24(%eax)
0x16eeb0:  movl   $3161095930, 20(%eax)
0x16eeb7:  movl   $1066426957, 40(%eax)
0x16eebe:  movl   $3539053052, 36(%eax)
0x16eec5:  movl   $0, 92(%eax)
0x16eecc:  movl   $0, 88(%eax)
0x16eed3:  movl   $0, 108(%eax)
0x16eeda:  movl   $0, 104(%eax)
0x16eee1:  movl   $0, 100(%eax)
0x16eee8:  movl   $0, 96(%eax)
0x16eeef:  pxor   %xmm0, %xmm0
0x16eef3:  movaps %xmm0, 64(%eax)
0x16eef7:  movl   $0, 60(%eax)
0x16eefe:  movl   $0, 56(%eax)
0x16ef05:  movb   $0, 52(%eax)
0x16ef09:  movb   $0, 53(%eax)
0x16ef0d:  movl   $0, 48(%eax)
0x16ef14:  movl   $0, 80(%eax)
0x16ef1b:  movl   $4294967295, 44(%eax)
0x16ef22:  movl   $0, 84(%eax)
0x16ef29:  popl   %ebp
0x16ef2a:  ret    
0x16ef2b:  nop    
0x16ef2c:  nop    
0x16ef2d:  nop    
0x16ef2e:  nop    
0x16ef2f:  nop
```

Xcode 4.3.1

iOS Simulator 5.1

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

I really appreciate your help.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having this issue running the app on the device. So I kept researching and it actually is a simulator bug. More info here: [What does this gdb output mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean)