# Error: Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, symbols

today I was working in xcode when this error showed up on start up of the app, whats wrong with my app?

> 2012-07-29 19:29:58.682 Champagne Pop[10601:1b03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-07-29 19:29:58.690 Champagne Pop[10601:1b03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-07-29 19:29:58.703 Champagne Pop[10601:1b03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-07-29 19:29:58.710 Champagne Pop[10601:1b03] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Answer (score 12):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317546/1441264) this is a bug in the iOS simulator but is not a problem when running on the actual device. This bug persists at least through Xcode 4.4.1 and the iOS 5.1 SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the debugger breakpoints & re-run. This worked for me.
Apparently the problem is working in iOS6 and should also be fine on the device.

Comment: Are you on iOS6 or 7? This was an old work-around, I can't recall which version of iOS6 it worked on.

Answer (score 3):

Try add in your project a

Security.framework

CoreFoundation.framework

from Simulator folder

Comment: This did not help in my case.

Comment: It seems, you trying compile for Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the debugger breakpoints & re-run. This worked for me. Apparently the problem is working in iOS6 and should also be fine on the device.

This is my issue. Remove the breakpoint, that's OK.