# iOS 6 streaming player com.apple.coremedia.networkbuffering bug

Tags: ios, streaming, ios-simulator, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

I'm having trouble on make my app(music and video stream player) running on iOS 6 simulator.

When I start a music ou video it crashes showing an error on this thread: com.apple.coremedia.networkbuffering

and this on log info:

```
2012-09-13 17:45:09.260 app[32563:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-09-13 17:45:09.260 app[32563:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-09-13 17:45:09.305 app[32563:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-09-13 17:45:09.307 app[32563:c07] handlePlaybackNowPlayingNotification
2012-09-13 17:45:09.308 app[32563:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
2012-09-13 17:45:09.308 app[32563:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
2012-09-13 17:45:09.318 app[32563:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-09-13 17:45:09.320 app[32563:c07] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
```

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController with http based stream, and it works fine on iOS 4 or iOS 5

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I"m having a similar problem.

Comment: If you've found a bug in the core of iOS, StackOverflow is unlikely to be able to help you. The Apple Dev forums or reporting the bug is more likely to get you a fix.

Comment: Just a note. I get the same problem in the simulator but it works fine on the device.

Comment: did you guys get any solution regarding MPMoviePlayerController issues on ios 6? If yes, please post the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem...

try to do this just after you instantiate your player:

```
[player prepareToPlay];
```

It should be called automatically when you call play but apparently on iOS 6 something goes wrong if you don't call it explicitly.

In my case it solved the problem.

Comment: Solved the problem for me as well. Beforehand I wasn't getting the `moviePlayerLoadStateChanged` notifications, now I am.

Comment: Yep, that seems to solve the problem, I added that line and until now no more errors like tha. Thank you

Comment: I added this line but am still getting errors similar to the ones in the OP's question.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

What you are observing is not a crash but an exception. You most likely have an exception breakpoint enabled and that leads you to the assumption that the app crashes.

That exception actually is properly handled (cought) by the SDK and does not cause an app crash.

Please note that this is only happening on the simulator, not on the device.

The issue is closely related to this issue [what-does-this-gdb-output-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean/8317546#8317546). The difference is that you won't get those error messages anymore but the exception's still are thrown (but also cought).

Comment: I have a better solution that lets you keep the all exceptions! Right click and edit it, and then under Exception chose Objective-C. If you're trying to actually debug C++ then this isn't great, but if you're an ordinary iOS app Objective-C is all you need! The movie player is throwing a C++ exception so this annoyance goes away!!

Answer (score 5):

i have verified using xcode 4.5+SDK6.0 versus xcode 4.4.1+SDK5.1 combinations that there is an issue with ios 6 version of the MPMoviePlayerController. i have only worked with iPads though.

here are my observations:-
- i have never seen the video play on ios 6.0 with my code that uses MPMoviePlayerController.
- with xcode 4.4.1 and SDK 5.1, i have seen the code work on ios versions 5.1, 5.0 and 4.3.
- with xcode 4.5 and SDK 6.0, the player always fails in the simulator, but most installations on ios 5.1 device work. i kept reinstalling the app on ios 5.1 device and trying out the player. it only failed once.

here are my observations when the player failed:
- some times when the player failed, i saw the logs that you mentioned above. other times, i didnt even see the logs.
- i put a breakpoint in the function that got the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification. then i looked for the errorLog in the player and there was none. i looked for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey and it was 0 (MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded). so MPMoviePlayerController had no clue anything had gone wrong!

conclusion: ios6 and/or SDK 6 have got a bug.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController  *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];



moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Note : Before iOS 6, no need to call [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play]; once you add player view to a view it will start to play but in iOS 6, you need to call play function explicitly

Answer (score 1):

i am having the same issue with MPMoviePlayerController for ios6. So i changed my code to fllowing and now it is working fine..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController  *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];



moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: In my case it was enough removing the:   moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved this problem yet, but it seems to be related in my particular case when `MPMoviePlayerController` is going to enter full screen, or when there is a potential lag for the controller.

I am not streaming content from the web, the content is on the device, so initially the content displays fine in the view.

My guess is that they have implemented a new feature into `MPMoviePlayerController` to prevent "dead time" during playback.  I have seen some apps that just hang when the movie data goes offline or you happen to walk out of range of your wifi"

My attempt to resolve this issue will be to look at the notification message passed to -

```
(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
```

this is done by querying the user info dictionary

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
```

the value for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey` is 0 in the case of this type of failure.

It's a starting point. My thought is to re-instate the movie at this point on this unique failure.

I will keep you posted on the results.

Comment: 0 equals to MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded. You probably do not want to start the movie again once it's reached its end.

Answer (score 0):

first I had done something like below

```
[self.player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.player.moviePlayer play];
self.player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
```

and when i deleted the below line

```
self.player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
```

problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problem with the code below, the player goes on full screen, but right after that, it closes and doesn't play the video at all.

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://streaming.disponivel.uol.com.br/video360p2/288148-1192657.mp4"];

```
    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [_player.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

    [_player.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    [_player.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];      

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_player];

    [_player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [_player.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to show live video on my app and I'm getting the same list of errors as above. I've found that `MPMoviePlayer` does not support larger data to show video but if you use smaller video data it works fine, throwing no errors. In fact it is not a problem of prepare to play and play properties of movie player.

If you need to show larger data then use webview on your app.