# MPMoviePlayerController stops playing after a few seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

`MPMoviePlayerController` stops playing after a few seconds,
this is the code I'm using:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://67.159.28.74:8730";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

player.view.hidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player prepareToPlay];

if(player){
    [player play];
}
```

The error im getting in the console is:

```
2012-09-23 18:07:56.618 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause

2012-09-23 18:07:56.619 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay

2012-09-23 18:07:56.638 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause

2012-09-23 18:07:56.638 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay

2012-09-23 18:07:56.643 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay

2012-09-23 18:07:56.645 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0

2012-09-23 18:07:56.646 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.

2012-09-23 18:07:56.648 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0

2012-09-23 18:07:56.648 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.

2012-09-23 18:07:56.650 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay

2012-09-23 18:07:56.652 Reader[696:c07] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0

2012-09-23 18:07:58.746 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0

2012-09-23 18:07:58.746 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.

2012-09-23 18:07:58.747 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1

2012-09-23 18:07:58.748 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 1

2012-09-23 18:07:58.748 Reader[696:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay`
```

Comment: Hi, Which iOS you are using?

Answer (score 9):

**solved it:**

I turned my MPMoviePlayerController into a property:

//add in header

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer;
```

//add in .m file

```
- (IBAction)playStream:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://67.159.28.74:8730";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    //Remember you have to add MediaPlayer.framework to your project
    /*[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:player];*/

    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;



    player.view.hidden = YES;

    self.myPlayer = player;

    [self.view addSubview:self.myPlayer.view];


    if(player){
      [self.myPlayer play];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to set a class variable like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

My code looks like this:

```
NSURL *theUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp4"];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theUrl];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
```

This works perfect for me!

Answer (score 3):

on xCode 4.6.1 it worked fine.

But i had this problem with xCode 5!

But this solution is very helpful:

"The solution is that the player would have to be an instance variable or property of the view controller. ie We must use the instance of MPMoviePlayerController

@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *myMovieController;"

Thank author very much!

And this is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
self.moviePlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[self.moviePlayerView prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayerView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
self.moviePlayerView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.moviePlayerView setContentURL:videoURL];

self.moviePlayerView.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
self.moviePlayerView.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerView.view];
self.moviePlayerView.shouldAutoplay = NO;
[self.moviePlayerView play];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this just after you instantiate your player:
`[player prepareToPlay]`

More info here: [iOS 6 streaming player com.apple.coremedia.networkbuffering bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414717/ios-6-streaming-player-com-apple-coremedia-networkbuffering-bug/12551702#12551702)

Comment: Not sure where I'm suppose to ad [player prepareToPlay] , I already have that in my code. Should I move that method somewhere else  or add an extra ,not really sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: I added the method [player prepareToPlay]  after [player play] ,and it still cuts off after a few seconds

Comment: still no luck i see other post with similar issue, but the problem isnt solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's work well for me in ios6

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ddd" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSLog(@"%@",resourcePath);
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting line of code which you are missing.

According to Apple's document

" When you add a movie player’s view to your app’s view hierarchy, be sure to size the frame correctly, as shown here:  http://tinyurl.com/9wgv9wc

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =

    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];

[player prepareToPlay];

[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's

[myView addSubview: player.view];

// ...

[player play];
```

http://tinyurl.com/aeh9f84

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the player would have to be an instance variable or property of the view controller. 
ie We must use the instance of MPMoviePlayerController

@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *myMovieController;