# UIWebView Movie Player getting dismissed iOS 6 bug

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

When I try to initiate a video to play (via YouTube) in a `UIWebView`, the video opens, then the debugger says:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
```

Here's a similar question: [MPMoviePlayerController stops playing after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556764/mpmovieplayercontroller-stops-playing-after-a-few-seconds-this-is-the-code-im-u)

My only problem is that with a `UIWebView`, I can't set up an `MPMoviePlayerController` to `prepareToPlay`. At least not as far as my knowledge goes. If anyone can help fix this problem, that would be amazing!

Comment: When using a web view to play video, the class that handles the playback is **not** `MPMoviePlayerController` even though the interface looks the same.

Comment: Ok. So how can I fix this issue then?

Comment: @Encephalon can u tell me what actually your problem. if your player automatically closes or any other problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have also faced a similar problem in iOS 6. The reason behind this is that when YouTube video is played in another than iOS6 version **viewWillDisappear** method is not called up. But in iOS6 this method is called up every time whenever a YouTube video is played. It may be an OS level bug but I am not sure about it.

However, I have fixed it and the steps are as below.

Add full-screen entry and exit notification, use a Boolean property, and updates it accordingly.

```
// Notification when the player moves to full screen

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeVideofullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

// Notification when the player exit from full screen.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeVideoExit:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

```
 - (void)youTubeVideofullScreen:(id)sender {
      //Update flag.
      isFullscreen = TRUE;
 }

 - (void)youTubeVideoExit:(id)sender {
        //Update flag.
        isFullscreen = FALSE;
  }

 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //Now you can use that flag and avoid the code execution which is interrupting the video
    
      if(!isFullscreen) {
       [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; 

       }
  }
```

Hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: not working for me :( I applied this to both `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: @NikitaP I don't Your Code how you doing same.you should ask a question separately rather than here...!!!

Comment: @Kamarshad: please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154137/video-embedded-on-a-link-not-working-on-uiwebview-with-ios6-simulator-or-device#comment19606770_14154137

Comment: @Kamarshad i want to close this default AVPlayer when this notification called UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification .

Comment: How can i rotate movie player?

Answer (score 4):

I just had this very same issue in one of our apps. Turns out we were setting the `UIWebView`'s HTML to an empty string in `-(void)viewWillDisappear`. Apparently this method is now being called in iOS 6 when displaying a fullscreen video from an `UIWebView`, so that's probably where your issue comes from.