# Playing youtube video fullscreen in UIWebView on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, youtube, fullscreen

I have a problem playing youtube videos in fullscreen mode within `UIWebView`. By default video is inlined. When I switch to fullscreen (native player button), video player is resized to fullscreen and after that is quits playing and page gets refreshed.

This works just fine is `iOS5` but not `iOS6`.

This is more obvious on iPhone cos player goes fullscreen mode as soon as video starts playing. As a results this videos can not be played on iPhone device using `iOS6.x`.

I know that `Apple` change its policy about youtube videos. But how does this helps me? How can I assure videos are also playing in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-(void)viewWillDisappear` is now (iOS6) called if you play a video in fullscreen mode

try registering for UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnter*(/Exit)*FullscreenNotification
and modifying viewWillDisappear like [UIWebView Movie Player getting dismissed iOS 6 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660857/uiwebview-movie-player-getting-dismissed-ios-6-bug)

Comment: This is the correct solution. Actually it's logical cos video is presented in some kind of a modalView which is pushed above webView. Thanks!