# Speech to text sdk freezes after video playback

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I'm using speech-to-text sdk provided by https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text

Recognizer works just fine until the moment I playback a video using MPMoviePlayerController.
Here is the code i'm using to call recognizer:

```
- (IBAction)actionBtRecognition:(id)sender {
    if(recognizer == nil){
       recognizer = [[SpeechToTextModule alloc] init];
    }
    [recognizer beginRecording];
}
```

To playback movie I used [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Application)

So, once I playback a movie and call recognizer, it's just freezes.
When I debug sdk source code, I was found that my voice is not recording.
Variable meterStateDB.mAveragePower is always = -120

Note that on my Mac iphone simulators all works perfect! But on real device (iphone 4, ios 5.1.1) happens the problem I described above. Maybe this is only my device problem?

I would be very grateful if someone will check the same thing on his own device.