# Getting the big warning/gdp output when I click on button

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing one application. In that I prepared one question with four answer boxes and every answer box has a one view with UILable and enabled the user interaction for both UIView and UILable and prepared the tap gestures for both with different tap gesture objects with same method and when I click any button at first time it will take some time to respond and print the below thing in console. Please provide some assistance with this issue.

```
2013-03-14 17:31:37.814 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library  /Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:37.826 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions  /AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.084 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.096 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.119 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
 Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.130 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.152 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
 Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.168 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.692 StudyApps[1971:12303] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Hear.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Hear:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Hear.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Hear, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Users/wifin/Desktop/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2013-03-14 17:31:38.692 StudyApps[1971:12303] Cannot find function pointer HearCFPlugInFactory for factory 8368FFAB-0147-4692-97ED-4D50A2483C6C in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x76f8fd0 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Hear.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

Comment: post button click code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls check this answer:
[What does this gdb output mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean)

Summary: this error is just console noise from a System framework only on Simulator, you should ignore it, it doesn't affect you.

Comment: Yes that's a bug in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Looking from your error it seems compiler is not able to locate Frameworks you have added into your project. Check that you have added required frameworks correctly.

**UPDATE**

After searching a little I came across few question which had similar issues and it seems that it is a confirmed bug of the iOS SDK 5 Simulator, which means you will be Ok if you run on device. Just try to run it on Simulator other than iOS 5.1 and you may not encounter this issue. I recommend you to upgrade your X Code as in Xcode 4.5 this issue is solved.

[Courtesy: originally answered by Till](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317546/818506)