# Unknown GDB Error

Tags: iphone

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

I have no idea what this error means in log navigator it shows when i press the play button on my app to play the audiofile and display multiple **UIViewControllers** using **NSTimer**.

When i use exception breakpoint to debug the app it crashes with the same message when i hit the play button on my app.

Is this something related to leaking memory or something else.

What does it mean. Any ideas please help.

Comment: Are you linking to the necessary frameworks?

Comment: i have avfoundationframework to play audiofile. do i need any other framework for playing audiofile

Comment: It looks like you also need Security.framework based on the contents of the error you posted.

Comment: check out [this probably related question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281261/symbol-not-found-cfxmlnodegetinfoptr-when-start-instruments)

Comment: i have xcode 4.2 and iphone 5.0 simulator. Is that the problem how can i check SDK Version

Comment: In BuildPhases have 11images in BundleResources do u think that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of the iOS 5 simulator .. its happened on the simulator when you try to play sounds , try it on the device and you will not have any problem.

Comment: You are very right. Thanks for your quick and right answer and saved me from wasting so many days on this little bug. Thanks again.